# C# Unions of Structs that Contain Arrays of Structs

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, marshalling, unions

I'm trying to create a union of multiple structs.  I'm having an issue with one struct that contains an array of another struct.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct FruitBasket
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Apples Apple;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Grapes Grape;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Oranges Orange;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 12)]
public struct Apples
{
    public int Color;
    public int Texture;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 15)]
    public Types[] Type;

}
```

If I use the Apples structs alone the marshaling works fine.  However if I try to do something like;

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi]
public class Buffet
{
    public UInt32 NumMeats;

    public UInt32 NumVeggies;

    public FruitBasket NumFruits;  //public Apples Apple; <-- works fine
}
```

I get the following error;

FruitBasket' from assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.

Comment: What is in `Grapes` and `Oranges`? Also what is `Types`?

Comment: @IllidanS4 Grapes and Oranges are also  structs but only contain basic types like Ints, Bools, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that an array is a reference type (the `MarshalAs` doesn't change that - it only applies when doing pinvoke). Which means there's a reference in the struct to an array somewhere else. And in your case, the memory location that stores that reference is shared with other stuff in the union, which can't really work.

So what you need is to have that array *in the struct*, which is [possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx), sort of, if using unsafe code. The catch is this:

> The only restriction is that the array type must be bool, byte, char, short, int, long, sbyte, ushort, uint, ulong, float, or double.

So with the `Types` you have there - it isn't an option. But if that could be changed to one of the supported types, you could do as such:

```
public unsafe struct Apples
{
    public int Color;
    public int Texture;

    public fixed int Type[15];
}
```

Edit: And yes, as @IllidanS4 mentions - if you need to use anything other than those types (a struct), you can add those 15 fields manually, one by one. Not very neat...

Edit 2: A second option would be to skip the union all together - make three separate structs and have the marshaller sort it out for you with `Marshal.PtrToStructure`. `MarshalAs` will work for the array in that case, avoiding the use of `fixed`. You will have to do it three times though, but it might be a more practical alternative.

Answer (score 0):

`MarshalAs` is substantially different from `FieldOffset` or `StructLayout`. `MarshalAs` is just a "normal" parameter that indicates to the Marshaller how to marshal the field, it modifies the unmanaged layout of the struct. On the other hand, `FieldOffset` directly modifies the managed layout of the structure, when you use it in C#. `MarshalAs` has no effect on the struct layout in the managed environment. Therefore, it won't make `Types` fixed-sized value array, so the CLR will still complain about a reference being overlapped by a value (contained in one of the other structs at the same offset).

For primitive types, you can use `fixed`, but it isn't available for `Type`, I am afraid. You're left to create a structure with 15 physical fields for each element of the "array", I guess. Don't forget that it will only work if `Types` is a struct (or enum), not a reference.

Still, this isn't usually the solution for a common problem, only in P/Invoke.

Comment: So what I'm hearing is that because Types is not a primitive time I'm going to have to make 15 instances of it in order to do the union.

Comment: @J.Morgan Exactly. In the article linked by Chris, you can see only primitive types are allowed in fixed arrays (although I am sure the CLR would support all types). Don't forget you would end up having 15 instances of `Types` on both ways.